# Omnisocial installation problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authorization

I am trying to install the Omnisocial gem into my Rails 3.1.0.rc4 application.

When I run bundle install I get the following error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "multi_json":
  In Gemfile:
    omnisocial depends on
      multi_json (~> 0.0.2)

    rails (= 3.1.0.rc4) depends on
      multi_json (1.0.3)
```

Anyway around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try https://github.com/excid3/omnisocial/

I just patched omnisocial for Rails 3.1 compatibility. Hopefully it gets merged into the main, but you can specify mine for the time being. The omniauth dependencies were old, so I updated those and fixed the auth to work with the latest omniauth as well.

Answer (score 2):

I've just released `omnipopulus` (`omnisocial` had to be renamed) 0.2.0, which includes excid3's work to make it Rails 3.1 compatible.